# 'Vary: If-None-Match' to cache mobile and desktop requests separately

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, varnish, http-caching

*Note: Please correct me if any of my assumptions are wrong. I'm not very sure of any of this...*

I have been playing around with HTTP caching on Heroku and trying to work out
a nice way to differentiate between mobile and desktop requests when caching using Varnish
on Heroku.

My first idea was that I could set a `Vary` header so the cache is Varied on `If-None-Match`. As Rails automatically sends back etags generated from a hash of the content the etag would vary between desktop and mobile requests (different templates) and so it would eventually cache two versions (not fact, just my original thoughts). I have been playing around with this but I don't think it works.

Firstly, I can't wrap my head around when/if anything gets cached as surely requests with `If-None-Match` will be conditional gets anyway? Secondly, in practice fresh requests (ones without If-None-Match) sometimes receive the mobile site. Is this because the cache doesn't know whether to serve up the mobile or desktop cached version as the `If-None-Match` header isn't there?

As it probably sounds, I am rather confused. Will this approach work in any way or am I being silly? Also, is there anyway to achieve separate cached versions if I am unable to reach the Varnish config at all (as I am on Heroku)?

The exact code I am using in Rails to set the cache headers is:

```
response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=86400'
response.headers['Vary'] = 'If-None-Match'
```

*Edit:* I am aware I can use `Vary: User-Agent` but trying to avoid it if possible due to it have a high miss rate (many, many user agents).

Comment: have you tried `Vary: User-Agent` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `Vary: User-Agent`. However you'll have many cached versions of a single page (one for each user agent).

An other solution may be to detect mobile browsers directly in the reverse proxy, set a X-Is-Mobile-Browser client header before the reverse proxy attempts to find a cached page, set a `Vary: X-Is-Mobile-Browser` on the backend server (so that the reverse proxy will only cache 2 versions of the same page) and replace that header with `Vary: User-Agent` before sending to client.

Comment: As I am using Heroku I can't change Varnish's configuration. User-Agent will work but I am trying to avoid that for the reasons you stated. Will update the question with that. Sorry :(.

Comment: Perhaps you could insert a rack middleware to set the X-Is-Mobile?

Answer (score 1):

If you can not change your varnish configuration, you have to make different urls for mobile and desktop pages. You can add some url-parameter (`?mobile=true`), add a piece in your path (`yourdomain.com/mobile/news`) or use a different host (like `m.yourdomain.com`).

This makes a lot of sense because (I've seen this many times, both in CMSs and applications) at some point in time you want to differentiate content and structure for mobile devices. People just do different things or are looking for different information on mobile devices...